# problems with generating rigs

Tags: rigging

what do I do when I have two models on the same blend file although in different layers and when I add two different metrigs to them I get the error can't add new bone root outside of edit mode incorrect armature for type utils

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, and was able to resolve it by renaming the armature of the 1st character from "rig" to "rig_a".